# Can i use shredded storage with RBS together in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, rbs, shredded-storage

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm with RBS and upgraded to share point 2016 and configured RBS, here in SP 2016 can i use shredded storage with RBS together

In this farm users upload documents and i created site collections using document center template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RBS and Shredded storage have very good relationship and they go along very well.
With this combination, you will get the advantage of Shredded storage as well as RBS.

read this blog which is for SharePoint 2013 but valid for SharePoint 2016.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briangre/2015/02/19/sharepoint-2013-shredded-storage-vs-rbs/

Comment: when i enable rbs for c.db blobs will go to storage in sql server and how shredded stroage work here and also i have some sites users archive daily 5000 docs which has some times 5 mb size files.